# How to delete these monero files on macOS?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, macos

I'm having a few problems with the monero-gui-wallet crashing and hanging so that it needs to be force quit to close it. I've deleted all the monero files I can find on my system but there are two I just can't get access to.

They are these two files:

```
/private/var/db/oah/<bunch-of-numbers>/monero-wallet-gui.aot

/private/var/db/oah/<bunch-of-numbers>/monerod.aot
```

Can anyone suggest a way to delete them because even using sudo on the command line to rm them does not work? I think if I can delete these two files things will start working again.